# error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer> cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated meth

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm, dagger-hilt

Error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer> cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements HiltWrapper_ActivityRetainedComponentManager_LifecycleComponentBuilderEntryPoint,

   javax.inject.Provider<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>> is injected at
          space.rodionov.swedishdriller.DrillerViewModel_AssistedFactory(�, drillerCatList, �)
      space.rodionov.swedishdriller.DrillerViewModel_AssistedFactory is injected at
          space.rodionov.swedishdriller.DrillerViewModel_HiltModule.bind(factory)
      java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>> is injected at
          androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.ActivityModule.provideFactory(�, viewModelFactories)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory java.util.Set<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultViewModelFactories.ActivityEntryPoint.getActivityViewModelFactory() [space.rodionov.swedishdriller.SwedishDrillerApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? space.rodionov.swedishdriller.SwedishDrillerApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? space.rodionov.swedishdriller.SwedishDrillerApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityC]
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
      dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultViewModelFactories.FragmentEntryPoint.getFragmentViewModelFactory() [space.rodionov.swedishdriller.SwedishDrillerApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? space.rodionov.swedishdriller.SwedishDrillerApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? space.rodionov.swedishdriller.SwedishDrillerApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityC ? space.rodionov.swedishdriller.SwedishDrillerApplication_HiltComponents.FragmentC][WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).
```

This error occures during building project on attempt to launch it.
It occures after I finished the ViewModel code, and called its methods from the Fragment.
It seems to me that I made mistake in ViewModel, but Hilt is new for me as well is Kotlin language.
Appreciate eny help.
Code:

In Fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DrillerFragment : Fragment(R.layout.cardstack_layout), CardStackListener {

    private val viewModel: DrillerViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val binding = CardstackLayoutBinding.bind(view)
        val drillerLayoutManager = CardStackLayoutManager(requireContext(), this) // ЧТО ПИСАТЬ В CONTEXT??
        val drillerAdapter = DrillerAdapter()
        binding.apply {
            cardStackView.apply {
                adapter = drillerAdapter
                layoutManager = drillerLayoutManager
                itemAnimator = null 
            }
        }

        viewModel.getLivedataList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            drillerAdapter.submitList(it)
        }
        viewModel.get4words()
    }
```

In ViewModel:

```
class DrillerViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val wordDao: WordDao,
    val drillerCatList: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList(),
    val mLivedataList: MutableLiveData<List<Word>>
) : ViewModel() {

    val shownCategoriesFlow = wordDao.getShownCategoriesNumbers()

    fun getLivedataList(): LiveData<List<Word>> {
        return mLivedataList
    }

    fun get4words() = viewModelScope.launch {
        shownCategoriesFlow.collect {
            it.forEach { catNumber ->
                drillerCatList.add(catNumber)
            }
        }
        wordDao.get4words(drillerCatList).collect {
            mLivedataList.value = it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make yours variables in constructor

```
    val drillerCatList: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList(),
    val mLivedataList: MutableLiveData<List<Word>>
```

as ordinary variables in class if you do no inject them via Hilt